# how to print variable number of characters in c using printf()

Tags: design-patterns, printf

i want to print variable number of # for making a pattern like this:

```
#  
##  
###    
####
```

but the code I am using is not working correctly.....Here's what I wrote for the first time:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void main()
{ int i;
  for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
  printf("%*c",i,'#');
}
```

And the output was:

```
#  
 #  
  #    
   #
```

then I tried to replace printf("%*c",i,'#');
with                    printf("%.*s",i,"#");
   but it still didn't work....
    this time the output was:

```
#
#
#
#
```

**note**: I want to do it with printf() only and not with the nested loop method because i want to  make some other pattern which  contains this part.... so if this one  is clear to me then I would be able to make that pattern.....

Comment: Did you read the documentation for format strings for `printf`? Documentation is helpful in understanding how functions and the format strings actually work. It's a much more efficient approach to learning how they work than randomly trying things you think should or might work. Your output is exactly what would be expected for how the format `%*c` works. Spoiler alert: the `printf` format string doesn't support custom padding characters. You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: simply, you can use 2 nested FORs. try yourself !

Answer (score -2):

```
you can use this one: (if helpful)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int i,y=0,j=1;
int main(){
hh:
for(i=1;i<=j;i++){

   printf("#");

}

printf("\n");
j++;
if(j!=5){
goto hh;    
}

}
```

Comment: please provide some explanation along with the code.

Comment: why on earth are you using `goto`s instead of a while loop. You are basically throwing away any optimization the compiler can do.